# $eq doesn't work for argument calculated in pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate(   
    {
        $addFields:{
            tomorrow: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        }
    },  
    {
        $addFields:{
            tomorrow_day:{ 
                $dayOfMonth : '$tomorrow'               
            },
            tomorrow_month: {
                $month : '$tomorrow' 
            },
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth : '$dateOfBirth'
            }           
        }       
    },
    {
        $match : {
            day: {$eq : 8}
        }
    }
)
```

This works and returns several documents.

Now I change it with:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate(   
    {
        $addFields:{
            tomorrow: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        }
    },  
    {
        $addFields:{
            tomorrow_day:{ 
                $dayOfMonth : '$tomorrow'               
            },
            tomorrow_month: {
                $month : '$tomorrow' 
            },
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth : '$dateOfBirth'
            }           
        }       
    },
    {
        $match : {
            day: {$eq : '$tomorrow_day'}
        }
    }
)
```

(I just replaced  `day: {$eq : 8}` with `day: {$eq : '$tomorrow_day'}`)
This query doesn't return anything.

How to fix this?

### P.S.

Corecction after Veeram response:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate(   
    {
        $addFields:{
            tomorrow: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        }
    },
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: [
                {
                    $and:[
                        {$eq: [{$dayOfMonth : '$dateOfBirth'}, {$dayOfMonth : '$tomorrow'}]},
                        {$eq: [{$month : '$dateOfBirth'}, {$month : '$tomorrow'}]},
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$match` takes query operator with values not variables similar to find queries.

Replace `$match` with `$redact`and use [$eq(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)  operator, which takes expression.

Something like

`$redact` will compare `$day` & `$tomorrow_day` and will `$$KEEP` document when match else `$$PRUNE`.

```
{
    $redact: {
        $cond: [{
                $eq: ["$day", "$tomorrow_day"]
            },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }
}
```

Based on your use case, you can merge `$addFields` and `$redact` into one stage so you need a single pass.

Comment: First of all - it works correct but I have several questions:

Comment: 1. Wht the difference between values and variables. I have not caught the cause why my example doesn't work

Comment: 2. When you say about merging $adFields and $redact you mean what I wrote in the topic update?

Comment: Yes for 2nd question. For the first one, Mongodb makes a distinction between [query comparison operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/), which can only be used in `$match` stage meaning static comparison (values) and [aggregation comparison operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/)  which allows variables in other stages that you can use for comparison.